# javascript and webview in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am a beginner in android platform and making an app with help of webview and javascript.when I run my code on real device it displays nothing.any help would be appreciable.
Here is my code:

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>       WebView view_1,view_2;
>       ImageView imageView;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     getSupportActionBar().hide();
>
>     String url_1="<script type=\"text/javascript”  src=\"http://ds.claymcenter.com/embed.js\">\n" +
>             "requestAd('Rh8uGpcrlYMjXN1s', 'banner', 'ads', '320' , ‘50');\n" +
>             "</script>\n" +
>             " \n" +
>             "<div id='ads'></div>";
>     String url_2="https://paytm.com/";
>
>     view_1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewGoogle);
>     view_2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewFacebook);
>
>     view_1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>     view_1.loadData(url_1, "text/html", null);
>
>     view_2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>     view_2.loadUrl(url_2);
>
>     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
>
>     imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             view_1.reload();
>             view_2.reload();
>
>         }
>     });
> } }
> ```

Comment: I noticed you're calling `loadUrl` immediately after `loadData`.  You may need to let the first page load entirely before loading the second page.  You can use `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` for that.

Comment: I have used two webviews.first webview was not loaded the url but second webview  able to load the url.

Comment: Sorry, should have noticed they were two different `WebView`s

Answer (score 0):

I always have a hell of a time trying to get things like this to work, and I don't remember exactly how I did some of this stuff, but here are some ideas:

First thing to try: Wrap that string in `url_1` in `<html><body>...</body></html>` tags.

Second thing to try:  You might have to use some kind of "onDocumentReady" event to call your javascript when the js file is completely loaded.

Third thing thing to try: Split out the function call like so:

```
String url_1="<script type=\"text/javascript\”  src=\"http://ds.claymcenter.com/embed.js\">\n" +
        "</script>\n" +
        "<div id='ads'></div>";


String call = "javascript:requestAd('Rh8uGpcrlYMjXN1s', 'banner', 'ads', '320' , ‘50');\n"
```

Load the html with the js file then use `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` to see when to load the javascript call (don't cut & paste this code, this is just a template):

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO: need to find out what is in url when html with js file loads
            if (urlMatches()) {
                view.loadData(call, "application/javascript", null); // not sure about the mime type
            }
        }
    });
```

This is like "onDocumentReady" but doing it in the Java code.

You might be getting stuck because of this statement from the `loadData` docs:

> Note that JavaScript's same origin policy means that script running in a page loaded using this method will be unable to access content loaded using any scheme other than 'data', including 'http(s)'. To avoid this restriction, use loadDataWithBaseURL() with an appropriate base URL.

So the last thing to try would be using `loadDataWithBaseURL`.

Comment: showing error : E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated issue, but if you think it's relevant you should add your logcat to the question.  Try on some different devices, I don't think you'll see the same error.